# Size of parities in counting partitions into odd parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions

Let $p_{odd}(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into odd parts ([see here](https://oeis.org/A000700)). For instance, one has the generating function
$$\prod_{k\geq1}\frac1{1-q^{2k-1}}.$$

> **QUESTION.** What is the size of this set
>   $$A_N:=\{n\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}: \text{$p_{odd}(n)$ is odd}\}$$
>   for large $N$?

**Note.** I do not expect this to be $\sim\frac12N$. Any solution or reference is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be linking to the wrong entry in OEIS -- that seems to be for partitions into odd and distinct parts.

Comment: Thank you, Lucia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that the generating function is 
$$ 
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-q^{2k-1}} = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1-q^{2k}}{1-q^k} = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1+q^k) \equiv \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-q^k) \mod 2. 
$$ 
Now use Euler's pentagonal number theorem, which says that the RHS is 
$$ 
1+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k (q^{k(3k+1)/2} + q^{k(3k-1)/2}).
$$
Thus $p_{\text{odd}}(n)$ is odd if and only if $n$ is of the form $k(3k\pm 1)/2$, so that $A_N$ has only on the order of $\sqrt{N}$ elements.

Comment: Equivalently $k(3k-1)/2$ for all integers $k$, from which it is easier to answer the original question that $A_N$ does, in fact, approach $N/2$ (as every 8 consecutive $k$ values give 4 even and 4 odd values).  [OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A001318)

Comment: @BrianHopkins no: the values of $k$ are not the same as the values of $n$

Comment: Thanks @FedorPetrov.  And thanks, Lucia, for finishing out the argument.

Comment: I appreciate all of your comments, suggestions and resolution.